# Azure Release Pipeline - Release to Universal Artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As it seems, that the PublishBuildArtifacts task is not available from Release Environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops

But as our clients pull new Artifacts Versions from the Azure Repository (universal packages), it would be a great benefit to have an opportunity to publish those Artifacts via an Release pipeline.

Is there any way available?

Comment: Do you want to publish pipeline artifact or Azure Artifact? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/artifacts-overview?view=azure-devops#supported-artifact-types

Comment: each of my builds has own build artifacts, my pipeline should create a new version and publish it to the azure artifacts service (as a universal package).

Basically my release pipeline should only do 3 things: 
- generate version
- take designated build artifact 
- publish designated build artifact with the generated version to azure artifacts

Comment: Ok, but to publish to Azure Artifact you sould use `UniversalPackages@0` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-your-packages

Comment: ah - so basically i cannot simply "forward" the build artifact, instead i have to create  a new one? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can download build artifact and then publish it from release pipeline if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this task to publish Universal Package from Release pipeline:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, helped me a lot. Just tried to upload the build artifact directly, but have to use the directory (that was my error)